# How to pipe a list of IDs into a MySQL select statement

Tags: mysql, macos, xargs

I have a text file with a list of IDs like this:

> 123
>      456
>      789

I would like to use them in queries to look up more information about these items.  So far I have unsuccessfully tried:
    `awk '{print $1;}' 'pathto/file.txt' | xargs echo "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='{}');" | mysql -u uname -p database`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IDS=$(cat /path/to/file)
IDS=$(echo $IDS | sed 's/\s\s*/,/g')
#or IDS=$(echo $IDS | awk '{$1=$1}1' RS= OFS=,) on OSX
echo "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in ($IDS)" | mysql -u uname -p database
```

Line 1 loads the ids into a variable, which allows to replace the line breaks easily in line 2, then replace the whitespace by commas to use an `IN ()` construct.

**Edits 1 and 2 see comments**

**Edit 3**

on OSX (which I don't use or have access to) it seems `sed` doesn't like my regex. As the OP points out, using `IDS=$(echo $IDS | awk '{$1=$1}1' RS= OFS=,)` as line 2 works around this.

Comment: This is on the right track, but the sed part is not inserting commas so the IN() construct is not working.

Comment: Just edited out a typo: The closing bracket in line 2 was in the wrong  spot

Comment: Second edit: Corrected the regex, should work now (tested on Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: On OSX, the sed syntax still didn't work, but I was able to do it with awk:  `IDS=$(echo $IDS | awk '{$1=$1}1' RS= OFS=,)`  Update and I'll select it as answered.  Thanks for the awesome answer!

Comment: Done! You might want to add the `OSX` tag to the OQ.